# Subsetting a Data Frame based on multiple wildcard criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

i have a Data Frame called `Test1` that contains 230k companies. what i need to do is to subset `Tests1` into a new DF called `FinalDS`.

i have created a list called `Customers` that contains several name variations of the clients (about 100k) that i need put into my `FinalDS` DF.
What i am looking for is R to look at my `Customers` DF and look for the customer name in the `Test1` DF but!.... what i need is R to scan the `Customers` DF and see if it can match any part of the customer name in the `Customers` DF to the `Test1` DF

For example:

i have this customer on the `Customers` DF:
`Centrica PLC`

But on the `Test1` DF i have `Centrica` so by difinition there will be no match. i know that i could just make all the customers match by deleting the `PLC` part from the `Customers` DF but i have a list of about 100k Customers.

this is the code that i have written:

```
Customers = c("Adidas","ADIDAS GROUP","ALIBABA GROUP","ALIBABA.COM (EUROPE) LTD"
              ,"Apple Asia Pacific Pte Ltd" ,"APPLE DISTRIBUTION INTERNATIONAL"
              ,"APPLE EUROPE LTD","Apple Sales International"
              ,"AVIVA-PLC","Aviva -Norwich Union"
              ,"Aviva -Norwich Union-MSP","AVIVA PLC"
              ,"AXA TECHNOLOGY SERVICES UK LTD","AXA UK PLC"
              ,"Bank of Baroda","Bank of Baroda"
              ,"BARCLAYS","BARCLAYS BANK PLC"
              ,"BARCLAYS PLC","BRAVURA SOLUTIONS LTD"
              ,"CENTRICA PLC","CISCO"
              ,"Cisco Systems LTD","CSC (NG)-MSP"
              ,"CSC COMPUTER SCIENCES LTD","EMC CORPORATION"
              ,"GE Infrastructure UK Limited","GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS INFORMATION TECHNOLOGIES GMBH")

FinalDS = subset(Test1, grepl(paste(Customers, collapse = "|"), Test1$Customer_Name))
```

All this does is try to match word by word what i have on my `Customer` list against the `Test1` DF

Help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
FinalDS = subset(
    Test1, 
    grepl(paste0("(", paste(Customers, collapse = "|"), ")"), Customer_Name))
```